# User simulation with jmeter for stress and scalability testing

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

Hi there I am trying to conduct stress and scalability testing for a web application. One of the problem is that it is not clear how many users the website can handle. So first I am conducting a stress testing with different user number. Consider below picture:

[image]

In the picture first I am starting with 100 user by gradually increasing the load. So i have requirement for example:

- Response time should not be 7 sec
- throughput should not fall under 35 request per second
- Percentage of error should not be more than 10 percent of the total request

So if this 100 user satisfies the requirement I will continue the test with 150 user and will go on until it breaks at least 2 requirement out of 3. And with that user I will perform the scalability test. Is this approach right? Please give me advise and how should I simulate user if not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is more or less right. However you could save your time and efforts for finding the breaking point of the system with a single test only, just start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until the maximum.

JMeter's theoretical limit for a single Thread Group is [`2,147,483,647`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647), your actual limit will be less as most probably your hardware resources are limited, check out [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter) article for more details.

Whatever, if you put a reasonably high number of threads in the Thread Group and configure the load to increase gradually you can run your test and pay attention to the following charts:

1. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) - shows the number of active users
2. [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime) - shows the system response time
3. [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) - shows the throughput (the number of requests per second)

At first stage of the test response time will be the same and the throughput will be growing as you increase the load. At the certain point of test the response time will start increasing and throughput will be going down - that would be the limit of your system (so called ["bottleneck"](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing))

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dmitri! Was really helpful...